# Auto-complete custom class methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am new to VS Code and I find myself not able to use its IntelliSense aka auto-complete feature.

I have already open up a folder and I don't see a "fire" icon asking me to setup project file. And I have this setting:

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
```

Yet all I got when hitting `⌃Space` is simple word-based suggestion (based on word used in the same file, not actually assembly or my custom classes)

I have already installed C# extension/Mono/Dotnet CLI, I don't know what else I could be missing at this point.

ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp#_intellisense

---

These are my Omnisharp settings in VSCode, is it not setup successfully? How could I ask VSCode to re-install Omnisharp?

```
  // Specifies whether the OmniSharp server will be automatically started or not. If false, OmniSharp can be started with the 'Restart OmniSharp' command
  "omnisharp.autoStart": true,

  // Specifies the level of logging output from the OmniSharp server.
  "omnisharp.loggingLevel": "information",

  // The maximum number of projects to be shown in the 'Select Project' dropdown (maximum 250).
  "omnisharp.maxProjectResults": 250,

  // Specifies the full path to the OmniSharp server.
  "omnisharp.path": null,

  // The time Visual Studio Code will wait for the OmniSharp server to start. Time is expressed in seconds.
  "omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout": 60,

  // Specifes whether OmniSharp should use VS Code editor settings for C# code formatting (use of tabs, indentation size).
  "omnisharp.useEditorFormattingSettings": true,

  // Launch OmniSharp with Mono.
  "omnisharp.useMono": false,

  // Pass the --debug flag when launching the OmniSharp server to allow a debugger to be attached.
  "omnisharp.waitForDebugger": false
```

Comment: Just an update, I suspect the issue is with my install order: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2030